# How to use vue components in a blade file like a radio button?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm wondering if I can use vue.js components in my blade file, but not components I've made, I want to use the ones that are already there or even use Element-ui components. Is this possible?

I use vue.js in the entire project but I'm making a pdf report and as far as I know I can only use blade to make the layout so I wanted to use the same stuff so it maintains a cohesive look. I'm using [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to create the pdf in laravel.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this package could help you: https://github.com/spatie/browsershot.You can configure it to wait for javascript or set a timeout before rendering

Comment: @RobbinBenard I can't just import it somehow in the blade file?